# Taking out my Subdirectory from my URL

Tags: command-line, apache2, webserver, web-development

I am hosting my own site..... Lets call it www.mysite.com.  It is an online store, and I am using Apache2, and the Magento Community 1.7 Platform.   I had an "Under Construction" page set in usr/var/www/ folder (while working on the site)  I also set a subdirectory in there called mystore.  I was doing all my work on the site in the subdirectory.  Now I would like make the website pull up, by just the url, without using the subdirectory (www.mysite.com/mystore/).  I have tried taking all the files from the subdirectory and placing them in usr/var/www.  That did not work.  When you go to pull up the page from your browser, it still trys to redirect you to the www.mysite.com/mystore.  Can someone please let me know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working on Ubuntu with Apache...

Apache setup serves `www.mysite.com` from the directory `/var/www/`, you probably moved the `mystore` folder to `/var/www` and the path to folder now is `/var/www/mystore` which Apache cannot handle according to your needs and
will probably serve (according to its directives) at `www.mysite.com/mystore`.

In order to fix that you will have to edit the site location, that is to *show Apache where to find the file you want to serve at `www.mysite.com`*. Since you dont give further details,
i assume that there is a configuration file for `mysite` located at `/etc/apache/sites-available` directory named either `default`,  `default-ssl` which are the configuration files coming with every Apache installation on Ubuntu **or** some other name you gave for site's configuration file.

You will have to edit the lines at this file accordingly.
The file may contain the following lines:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
  <Directory /var/www/>
[...]
```

change to:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/mystore
<Directory /var/www/mystore/>
```

save the file and execute the following in order for Apache to load the new configuration:

`sudo service apache2 reload`

You can find more information on how to configure Apache at [Official Ubuntu Documentation -HTTPD - Apache2 Web Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/httpd.html) section.